# Is there anyway making ADO.NET work on .NET Core?

Tags: ado.net, odp.net, .net-core

I need ODP.NET (Oracle Data Providers for .NET) on .NET Core but can't find anyway to make it work.

When I reference `OracleConnection` or `OracleCommand` classes, the project needs `System.Data` assembly which I can't find in .NET Core.

So isn't there any solution to use ADO.NET on .NET Core?

Comment: There is only about 25% .NET Core uploaded on GitHub..
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/01/28/net-core-open-source-update.aspx

Comment: Are you getting this error?  

    The type 'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Comment: @CarlProthman It's exactly that error. But the problem is it is not possible to add **System.Data** into a .NET Core assembly. It is not compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [System.Data.Common](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Common) contract is available for providers to start implementing against. So far, the only implementations on .NET Core that I know of are [System.Data.SqlClient](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient) and [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite](https://github.com/aspnet/DataCommon.SQLite).

Comment: With [System.Data.Common](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Common) at least I managed to make **SqlClient** to work. As **ODP.NET** is not still ported to .NET Core I can't make it work. It was exactly what I was looking for. It's strange that my Visual Studio's intellisense can't find the package in project.json. So I was not aware of it.

Comment: Yves, may I ask how you got it to run? In my machine, it fails with "invalid assembly format" at runtime.

Comment: As well as Npgsql (PostgreSQL)